# JavaFX Table fx:factory show ImageView

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I just completed [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm). One question remains open for me: How can I use the `fx:factory` to display a graphic in a cell? For example a Gender-Symbol for each Person. The Symbol would lies in the Resource Folder of my Maven Project.

Comment: Check out [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html).

Comment: You need to implement a custom cell type, add a `static` method for creating a `cellFactory` returning this cell type and use `fx:factory` to use this method to create the `cellFactory` in the fxml.